# Check if ffmpeg RTSP stream stopped because of input or timeout

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm using the following command to record a RTSP stream to a file, for a given amount of time (in this example 30 seconds):

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://streamurl:554/ch0" -t 30 output.mp4
```

Sometimes the source stream is closed-interrupted-finished-shutdown-whateverNameYouWant before the desired timeout (in this example 30 seconds), and the ffmpeg process is finished (with no errors).

I want to know how can I programmatically check if the above `ffmpeg` command was finished because of the desired timeout (`-t <duration>` flag), or because the input stream was interrupted.

In other words, I want to know when a problem occurred with the input stream, given that `ffmpeg` shows no errors when the input stream is closed/interrupted.

Comment: If [output file duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/) is < `-t` then maybe you can assume a network issue.

Comment: Then how can i check that a network issue happened? or comparing the file duration is the only way?